# HOW TO SPLIT OAX to ETH

Tags: go-ethereum

I am not very technical. I want to know if there is an easier way to split eth from OAX tokens. I mistakenly brought OAX tokens from ETH using my exchange instead of wallet

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you will need to contact the exchange as they might have control over your the account on which tokens were awarded.